# How to coalesce 3D arrays with different dimensions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have 3 3D array (60, 10, 20), (60, 20, 10), (60, 30, 30). I am wondering how to combine these arrays to a single array with a dimension of (60, 60, 60)

Comment: How would you combine them? Not speaking in terms of code, but what's the logic behind arriving at `(60, 60, 60)`?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late reply. My arrays are in (time, lat, lon) dimensions. I'll need to take average for them. The size is not the same so I think I may need to weight them by size. If I can combine them together I don't need to weight them.

Comment: Okay, but *how* do you want to combine them? Since the first dimension is similar for all arrays, you basically have the following shapes (dividing by 10): `(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)`. How do you want to combine these arrays in order to arrive at shape `(6, 6)`? For example, what should be the content of `final[0, 0]` or `final[5, 5]`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! all of these 3 arrays have same time dimensions. So I think the time dimension can stay the same. lon and lat dimensions are different, which means these data points are in different locations (3 maps). I want to combines three pieces of map in one single map. The final shape should be (time, lat_new, lon_new) with a size of (60, 60, 60). Is it possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but the question is, again, *how* they should be combined. With *how* I mean the logic behind combining them, not how to realize it in a certain programming language for library. It's up to you to provide this logic. I'll give you three example arrays in the following. Please update your question with the desired output if you would combine these three example arrays (i.e. hardcode the result: `output = [[?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?], ...]`. These are the arrays: `a = np.arange(0, 2).reshape(1, 2); b = np.arange(2, 4).reshape(2, 1); c = np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3, 3)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.